# Text wrapping is not working for "SCNText" node

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am able show `SCNText` in AR environment but when I tried to wrap the text in container of fixed width and height, instead showing it in multiple lines its getting overlapped.

```
let text = SCNText(string: ktext, extrusionDepth: 0.0)
text.name = "text"
text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = color
text.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: size)
text.truncationMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
text.isWrapped = true
text.truncationMode = kCATruncationMiddle
text.containerFrame.size = CGSize(width: 3, height: 1)
```

[image]

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: yes, adjusting the font size.

Comment: bigger size font with smaller scale factor. 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85368

Comment: how can we have the text horizontally wrapped? in X axis?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a "normal" font size and containing frame on the SCNText object, and then set a scale on the node that contains it, everything wraps as expected. Something like:

```
let extrudedText = SCNText(string: definition.text, extrusionDepth: 0.1)
extrudedText.font = UIFont(name: definition.fontname, size: 0.2)!
...
extrudedText.font = UIFont(name: definition.fontname, size: 20)! 
extrudedText.containerFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 500.0))
...
scale = SCNVector3Make(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
```